# How do I update "/etc/fstab" for a usb card-reader?

Tags: ubuntu, usb

I inputted a partitioning standard, msdos, and got a message: you may need to update "/etc/fstab".

My usb card-reader will not mount now. "lsblk" shows sdb/sdb1, but sdb/sdb1 will not mount. Appears that I need to update /etc/fstab, but not sure if this is the only reason.

To update /etc/fstab, I tried "mount -a"; didn't work - haven't found any other commands for it yet.

The output is " / = ignored" "/tmp = already mounted". I didn't put anything into "/etc/fstab" as permission denied. Partitioned with "sudo fdisk /dev/sdX"

```
parted /dev/sdb1 print
Error: /dev/sdb1: unrecognised disk label
Model: Unknown (unknown)                                                  
Disk /dev/sdb1: 15.9GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

```
 parted /dev/sdb print
Model: Generic STORAGE DEVICE (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 15.9GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  15.9GB  15.9GB  primary
```

update: after jumping through numerous hoops, deleting, creating, partition standard changed, formatting... It is now partitioned and recognized.

Comment: what's the output of `mount -av`? what did you put into `/etc/fstab`? what did you partition the disk with?

Comment: check as well this: https://blog.hostonnet.com/parted

Comment: try editing `/etc/fstab` with `sudo`, you need elevated permissions to edit that file. please also put the update to the ticket body instead of a comment.

Comment: @Bart Tried in sudo, didn't work.

Comment: what does `lsattr /etc/fstab` say?

Comment: and, more importantly, what did you try to put inside `fstab`? and, did you format the drive to `FAT`/`FAT32`, since you created `msdos` partition table?

Comment: @Bart Thanks Bart. I went around in circles, but got there. I redid the partitioning standard to 'gpt', but then somehow it got erased and then, if I recall correctly, I put it to msdos. I only use linux. Does it really matter if it is 'msdos' or 'gpt'? I posted a new question about 'partitioning standard'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formatting seemed to be the key. After that I had to redo some things involving the deleting and creating partitions and altering the partition standard. I don't remember the exact sequence of things.

Comment: Thanks to all who contributed!